# Adding a questioning system to a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make my discord bot have a command, where if you type ">dm [user] apply", the user is sent a series of questions where he has to answer the individual question, and only then the next question will come, kind of like an application bot, I would also like the bot to collect all these answers and then put them into an embed with all of them. Right now, I have no idea how to do that, I am new to coding.

````
@bot.command()
async def dmme(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message):
    if message == None:
        await ctx.send('The correct format is: ">dm [user] [message]/apply')
    elif message == "apply":
        await user.send("What is your discord username?")
    else:
        await user.send(message)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNELID)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed test", description="A test for my discord bot", color=0x5bcdee)
        embed.add_field(name="Message sent:", value=message, inline=False)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        # just so i can see every dm (a bit creepy ik but will be changed)
        print('"' + message + '"' + ' sent to ' + str(user))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        channel = bot.get_channel(CHANELID)
        await channel.send(f"{message.author} sent:\n```{message.content}```")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
````

I came up with that, the problem is it only sends one message, and sends the reply immediately, so I have no idea how to add followup questions. I also logs the messages it sends itself, which results in both the user and the bot in the logged messages channel. Could somebody explain to me, how I should log only the user's messages and then store them in temporary memory to send after the end of the question form, and show me an example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: YOU have to keep track of the state of things.  You will need a table that maps the user identifier to their current "question number".  Then, when you receive a message, you can see if they are in the middle of a question sequence, and ask the next question.

Comment: Could you help me implement that table? I have no clue on where to start with that

Comment: This is basic Python programming.  A dictionary with the author ID as the key would do it.  You can store anything you need to remember in the dictionary value.

Answer (score 0):

The process for collecting successive responses consists of:

- Send a message in the channel with the question;
- Use [bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) to capture the user's reply message;
- Repeat the procedure for the next question.

So, you can create a function that performs these steps and returns the answer and later use it to make your questionnaire.

Example:

```py
async def ask(question: str, user: discord.User) -> str:
    """Send the question to the user and return the answer"""

    def check_msg(message: discord.Message):
        return message.author == user and message.channel == user.dm_channel

    await user.send(question)
    reply = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check_msg, timeout=600)
    return reply.content


@bot.command()
async def dmuser(ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.User, *, questions: str):
    questions = questions.split(";")   # provide the questions separeted by ;
    emb = discord.Embed(
        title="Questionnaire",
        description=f"Answers by {user}",
        color=0x5bcdee
    )
    for question in questions:
        reply = await ask(question, user)
        emb.add_field(name=question, value=reply, inline=False)
    await ctx.reply(embed=emb)
```

Comment: I'm getting a "NameError: name 'check' is not defined" error, perhaps you mean "check=check_msg"

Comment: You are right. I'm fixing this issue